# How to fix htaccess loop?

Tags: .htaccess

i have 2 sub directory inside directory /var/www/html

```
1-admin
2-user
```

I want do this if user do request http://localhost -> open sub directory user without change url

and if do request http://localhost/panel -> open sub directory admin without change url 
this is my code on htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user/ [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/$1 -f

 RewriteRule /panel/(.*)$ /admin/ [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition that prevents the rewriting to get applied again and again:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/panel
RewriteRule ^/?panel(.*)$ /admin$1 [NC,END]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /user$1 [NC,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: The requested URL /useruser/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: can u give me solution for this error ? and thanks for reply

Comment: Sounds like your application uses absolute paths instead of relative paths. That is nothing you should try to work around by means of rewriting. Try to fix your application instead. So references (link) in the html pages you hand out should point to `some/file`, _not_ to `usr/some/file` and certainly not to `/user/some/file`.

Comment: it is redirect me to localhost/user i want redirect with out change url http://localhost  = > /var/www/html/user

Comment: That is what the rules implements. If that does not work then either `/user` does not get matched to `/var/www/html/user` (that has nothing to do with rewriting then, it is a question of setup of the http host) or that dynamic configuration file does not get applied at all (again a configuration thing). Please test if that file gets applied at all.